# Is there a Windows 2003 Server Service Pack 3?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service-pack

I am about to request a hotfix for Windows 2003 Server. As far as I am aware there is no publicly available Service Pack 3. However on the hostfix request page I see this:

[image]

I am guessing this is a mistake?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a mistake, though. As you may know the service packs are cumulative update bundles, so this fix was likely aimed at SP3 before MS decided there are not enough fixes to justify an SP3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No. There is no SP3.

You would be correct, there is no SP3 for Windows 2003.  Here is a blog post from TechNet explaining this:
(Emphasis added.)

> We have received inquiries from our
> customers and partners on whether or
> not there will be a need for a Service
> Pack 3 for Windows Server 2003.
> **Microsoft will not have a SP3 release
> for Windows Server 2003.**

- Source: TechNet Blogs, Microsoft Windows Server Team, 2009-09-15, [*Support changes coming July 2010 for Windows 2000 Server and Windows Server 2003*](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2009/09/15/support-changes-coming-july-2010-for-windows-2000-server-and-windows-server-2003.aspx)
- Related: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003#Updates